# A control for multiple instances of a Form

Tags: winforms

I have a WinForms app (with DevExpress v 10.2). 
I have to resolve the following task. I have a 'child' Form - it consists of several Controls and may be encapsulated into a Control; let's call it 'child Control'.

I need to create a 'parent' Form that contains series of the 'child' Form instances. The 'children' are located in the Parent Form from top sown to the bottom. In other words, every 'child control' occupies the whole width of the Parent Form; 1st 'child control' is located at the top of the Parent Form; 2nd 'child control' is located below the 1st one etc.

Count of the 'child controls' mat be dozens, so the Parent Form should have vertical scrolling.

What is a best way to implement this - using standard WinForms controls, or maybe DevExpress WinForms controls?

Answer (score 1):

Look at FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel.  Either will do what you suggest.